# Background Image not repeating on mobile screens

Tags: css

See image here: http://postimg.org/image/xa6pzd1df/
Website is: http://blackfridaymagazine.com/papa-johns-free-pizza-march-madness/09512

```
    #main {
    background: url(img/gray-pattern.png) repeat center center #f3f3f3;
    color: #000;
    }
```

Dark gray and light gray backgrounds at bottom should repeat but they do not...

Comment: Have you tried it? Please accept the answer if it has helped.

Answer (score 0):

When you repeat an image across the x axis on fluid or full-width layouts, you’d think it would fill the entire width of the browser window no matter the size of the window. Well it does, but what happens is that if the window area is really small, like on mobile devices, the repeated background stops short of the far right edge of the window.

The solution is that you need to add a `min-width` like this:

`min-width: 1024px;/*specify your width here */`.